# How to catch splitted string in java Stream

Tags: java, java-8

So let's say that we have a string: "randomText1 randomText2" in an array, which is loaded into a Stream.

Now I go over all the lines in this stream, and I split every line at the space character.

```
strings
                        .map(string -> string.split(" "))
                        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                        .collect(new MyClass(string1, string2));
```

How can I get the both sides of the string and do whatever I want with them from there on?

From Oracle docs ([Oracle doc link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2-2227132.html)) I only managed to find some harder cases where one would be using a `Map<>` for instance. But I fail to fit their solutions to this more simpler problem of mine.

Comment: Why don't just use `String[] splitted = string.split("\\s+"); new MyClass(splitted[0], splitted[1]);`?

Comment: And what are you expecting that `collect` call to do? (It sounds like you might just want one `map` call, but it's hard to tell at the moment.)

Comment: @Luiggi, I want to get more comfortable with the new Java 8 features. Jon, I guess it is indeed wrong of me to use it here. But even then, I don't know how to handle the string stream I just got from flatMap().

Comment: *I want to get more comfortable with the new Java 8 features* but you **don't need it** for this case. The fact you have a hammer doesn't mean you will use it as a saw.

Comment: Take the string split it by ` `  and assign to a string array. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `flatMap` is not the right tool for the job. What you apparently want to do is

```
strings.map(string -> string.split(" ", 2))
       .map(array  -> new MyClass(array[0], array[1]))
```

You may process the stream further by using `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to get a `List<MyClass>` or `.findAny()` to get a single `MyClass` instance (if any).

Generally, streaming an array is only useful if you want to treat all elements uniformly, i.e. *not* if their position has a special meaning which has to be preserved for subsequent operations.

---

And *if* you really want to create a flat stream of words or tokens, you shouldn’t use the combination of `String.split` and `Arrays.stream` as that will create and fill an unnecessary intermediate array. In this case use

```
strings.flatMap(Pattern.compile(" ")::splitAsStream)
```

<sup>see [`Pattern.splitAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

It was an interesting challenge even if streams should not be used for such simple tasks. Here's the complete code:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = {"randomText1 randomText2"};
        MyClass myClass = Arrays.stream(strings)
                .map(string -> string.split(" "))
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .collect(new MyCollector());
        System.out.println("myClass = " + myClass.toString());
    }
}

class MyCollector implements Collector<String, List<String>, MyClass> {
    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<String>, String> accumulator() {
        return List::add;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<List<String>> supplier() {
        return ArrayList::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<String>> combiner() {
        return (strings, strings2) -> {
            strings.addAll(strings2);
            return strings;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<String>, MyClass> finisher() {
        return strings -> new MyClass(strings.get(0), strings.get(1));
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}

class MyClass {
    String s1;
    String s2;

    public MyClass(String s1, String s2) {
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass{" +
                "s1='" + s1 + '\'' +
                ", s2='" + s2 + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s wasting a lot of resources processing an entire stream to finally drop everything but the first two elements…